# Add ONE static row to a dynamic table

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a uitableviewcontroller class that is displaying a table dynamically.

I want the first row of the table to be pre-defined, static, and always the same.

(I want it to have the behaviour of a (+), i.e. to add a new record to the table.)

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: A dynamic table whose first row never happens to change was a “static” first row eh? Or make it a table view header?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: @PGDev , there's really no need to "add code" for very basic questions like this.  There is nothing, whatsoever, the OP can offer in code that would help one way or the other.  Either you know how to do it or not. You just have to wait until an experienced programmer comes along, with the time to type out an answer.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible this trick will help you. This is a basic in doing iOS tables:

It looks like your data is in "allConversions":

```
numberOfRowsInSection {
  return allConversions.count
}
```

So to make the cells, you do this:

```
cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath {
  theRow = indexPath.row
  data = allConversions[ theRow ]
  your cell ... load it up with that data
  return cell
}
```

## One weird trick ..

Actually **add 1** to the number of rows returned

```
numberOfRowsInSection {
  return allConversions.count + 1
}
```

So when loading a cell, you actually subtract 1,

```
cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath {
  theRow = indexPath.row
  data = allConversions[ theRow - 1 ]
  your cell ... load it up with that data
  return cell
}
```

But!  Row "0" is special:

```
cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath {

  theRow = indexPath.row

  // row 0 is special

  if theRow == 0 {
      cell ... your special cell
      return cell
  }

  data = allConversions[ theRow - 1 ]
  your cell ... load it up with that data
  return cell
}
```

That's how you do it in many cases.

## Also consider a table "header"

Table headers are extremely annoying, for various reason.  They are "just a view"; they don't look anything like your table cells; Apple's layout of them is totally useless; and they (sometimes) don't move.

In some cases you want a table header.

In other cases you simply want to add a new row to the table (for some reason or another).

If you want to add a new, "extra" row to a table, you simply do it as above - add to the count in numberOfRowsInSection, and then carefully adjust the row number in cellForRowAt.

Comment: Cheers @Fattie! Thanks for the thorough explanation and possibilities!

Comment: my pleasure, great question @Nouman , looking forward to your next one